# Cannot resolve symbol 'player' error when coding a mc mod

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am creating a minecraft forge mod, and for a start, I just want to send a message in chat (also, I am new to modding).

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import com.mojang.logging.LogUtils;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

// The value here should match an entry in the META-INF/mods.toml file
@Mod(ExampleMod.MODID)
public class ExampleMod {
    //Mod ID Definition
    public static final String MODID = "modid";
    // Reference slf4j logger
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();
    player.sendMessage(new TextComponentString("This is sendmessage example string."));
}
```

On the player.sendMessage(new... line of code I am getting an error on player, stating:

Cannot resolve symbol 'player'

I suppose that is because I don't have player defined and it is defined in some other file, but I don't know which one and how to properly define it.

Comment: You need to get a PlayerEntity, as far as I can tell. For instance, `String message = "Some text";
ITextComponent msg = new StringTextComponent(message);
PlayerEntity player = Minecraft.getInstance().player;
player.sendMessage(msg, player.getUUID());`

Comment: This code might not be right, but the bottom line is that you can't just make up variables and try to use them without first declaring the variables and assigning to them a viable object.

Comment: Did you just stick a statement directly in a class with no method to hold it?